# UIlocalnotification schedules daily - 8:00 - 12:00 and 16:00

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

enable uilocalnotification 
Need to enable this notification schedules daily, I'm not getting, I created 3 different methods for each hour worked but it is not.

8:00 AM

12:00 AM

4:00 PM

```
-(void)Hour_08 {
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ 08:00", self.DayNow];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str];

    UILocalNotification *OitoHorasNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    [OitoHorasNotification setFireDate:date];
    OitoHorasNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    [OitoHorasNotification setAlertBody:@"is now 08:00"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:OitoHorasNotification];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [this site](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html) as it suggests you use `NSHourCalendarUnit` instead of `NSDayCalendarUnit` which would be the case if you performing notifications after whole days. Or Maybe you are performing Notifications for whole days and therefore your code would be correct I would of miss read you question